# PWA through PowerBI missing Priority

Tags: project-server, pwa, powerbi

I am looking to pull data from PWA into PowerBI.   When I add the Project table in, I don't see the Project field "Priority"  This is kind of a key field for us and I don't know where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.   It is in tasks.   If you have a row and the TaskIndex = 0 then that contains the projects priority.